# How to make pdf Reader Android app to take pdf from assets folder?

Tags: android, pdf

I tried:

```
package com.example.dell.pdfreader;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView img;
    private int currentpage = 0;
    private Button next, previous;
    File file;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
        previous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.previous);
       //  file=getFile();


        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                currentpage++;
                render(file);
            }
        });


        previous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                currentpage--;
                render(file);
            }
        });
    }

    private void render(File file) {

        try {

            img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

            int width = img.getWidth();
            int height = img.getHeight();

            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);





            PdfRenderer renderer = new PdfRenderer(ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY));

            if (currentpage < 0) {
                currentpage = 0;

            } else if (currentpage > renderer.getPageCount()) {


                currentpage = renderer.getPageCount() - 1;

                Matrix matrix = img.getImageMatrix();

                Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);

                renderer.openPage(currentpage).render(bitmap, rect, matrix, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);

                img.setImageMatrix(matrix);
                img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                img.invalidate();

            }


        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();


        }
    }

    private File getFile() {
        File file=new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(null),"Example.pdf");;
        byte buffer[]=null;
        OutputStream output = null;


        InputStream input = null;
        try {
            input = this.getAssets().open("Example.pdf");

            buffer = new byte[input.available()];
            input.read(buffer);
            output = new FileOutputStream(file);
            output.write(buffer);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this,"File not Found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return null;
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this,"Failed to open",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return null;
        }

    return file;
    }
}
```

**Above code generated Following Error:**

```
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
> 'java.lang.String java.io.File.getPath()' on a null object reference
> 03-18 15:42:16.245 6826-6826/com.example.dell.pdfreader W/System.err: 
> at
> android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.openInternal(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:269)
> 03-18 15:42:16.245 6826-6826/com.example.dell.pdfreader W/System.err: 
> at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.open(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:200)
> 03-18 15:42:16.246 6826-6826/com.example.dell.pdfreader W/System.err: 
> at
> com.example.dell.pdfreader.MainActivity.render(MainActivity.java:76)
> 03-18 15:42:16.246 6826-6826/com.example.dell.pdfreader W/System.err: 
> at
> com.example.dell.pdfreader.MainActivity.access$100(MainActivity.java:26)
> 03-18 15:42:16.246 6826-6826/com.example.dell.pdfreader W/System.err: 
> at
> com.example.dell.pdfreader.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:47)
> 03-18 15:42:16.246 6826-6826/com.example.dell.pdfreader W/System.err: 
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5265) 03-18 15:42:16.246
> 6826-6826/com.example.dell.pdfreader W/System.err:     at
> android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21534) 03-18 15:42:16.246
> 6826-6826/com.example.dell.pdfreader W/System.err:     at
> android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 03-18 15:42:16.247
> 6826-6826/com.example.dell.pdfreader W/System.err:     at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 03-18
> 15:42:16.247 6826-6826/com.example.dell.pdfreader W/System.err:     at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 03-18 15:42:16.247
> 6826-6826/com.example.dell.pdfreader W/System.err:     at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728) 03-18
> 15:42:16.247 6826-6826/com.example.dell.pdfreader W/System.err:     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 03-18 15:42:16.247
> 6826-6826/com.example.dell.pdfreader W/System.err:     at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
> 03-18 15:42:16.247 6826-6826/com.example.dell.pdfreader W/System.err: 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Comment: file==null. You never gave it a value. You never initialized it. You never assigned a File object to it.

Comment: You are never calling getFile().

Comment: `output.write(buffer);`. Ok. But add output.close();.

Answer (score 3):

First, as noted in the comments, `file` is `null`, because you never set a value on it.

Second, for a PDF in assets, **there is no file**. Use `openFd()` on `AssetManager` to get an `AssetFileDescriptor` on the asset, then call `getParcelFileDescriptor()` on the `AssetFileDescriptor` to get the `ParcelFileDescriptor`.

Third, `PdfRenderer` does not handle arbitrary PDF files. It is there for print preview, nothing more. Most likely, you will need to use [something else](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/04/options-viewing-pdfs.html).

Comment: Thanks it helps me.

Comment: i did as you say but it show :

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed

Comment: @VikkiAsati: You will need to tell the build tools to not compress PDF files. Add `aaptOptions { noCompress 'pdf' }` to your `android` closure in your `build.gradle` file. See [this example](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider/blob/v0.5.0/demo/build.gradle#L14-L21).